# Cloud composer on Cloud Run For Anthos feasible on GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-composer

I’m thinking of using Cloud composer on Cloud Run For Anthos to leverage autoscaling and kubernetes executor from k8s and hybrid/multi-cloud from Cloud composer. Is this a feasible path? If so would there be a guide for this setup? Or is there a easy and better way to set up Airflow on GKE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloud Composer uses managed GKE instance and it is managed for you by Google team. It has built-in scalability etc. (there is a talk about it at the summit next week BTW https://airflowsummit.org/sessions/2021/autoscaling-airflow/)

It uses Celery Executor exclusively though and you cannot change it to KubernetesExecutor